Functional Analysis over a Ring.
In functional analysis we study infinite dimensional vector spaces of a field $\mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$). Is there functional analysis over a general ring $S$? (That takes into account its topology)

Not over any ring (for example, over a finite field you will not find an interesting topology), but there are generalizations. For example, there are books about functional analysis over the $p$-adic fields.

You'll probably run across a few resources that examine functional analysis using quaternions.

You take a general ring speak of "its topology". Which? Also, are you familiar with Berkovich spaces?
